# Why am I suddenly able to connect to the SQL Server with Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, dropwizard, sqljdbc

As I mentioned in a previous question, I'm working on a program that will connect to SQL Server for a simple search, using Windows authentication.  I was able to set up the program with dropwizard to make a simple select query.  However, I continued to receive the following error for an unsatisfied link:

```
MultiException[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I, java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$59/15254314@11a5965]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
at com.home.example.SQLApplication.main(profile_app3Application.java:13)
Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$59/15254314@11a5965
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.execute(QueuedThreadPool.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.execute(SelectorManager.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.doStart(ManagedSelector.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:428)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext(Native Method)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.GenerateClientContext(AuthenticationJNI.java:58)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.SSPIData(SQLServerConnection.java:1924)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2323)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
at io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.start(ManagedPooledDataSource.java:37)
at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
... 7 more
```

I thought that the error was due to an issue with my PATH, but it points towards the correct sqljdbc dll.  I also pointed it towards the driver, sqljdbc41.jar.  I then included that jar in the modules in the project structure.  None of these worked.  Then, I deleted the dropwizard jdbi and db dependencies from the pom file, and put them back in.  After this, the program was able to work.  What I don't understand is what happened and why it resolved.  t this point, I'm assuming it was an issue with my dependencies and they needed to be reimported, but any thoughts on this would be welcome.

Comment: Accessing MS SQL Server using Windows Authentication requires a shared library in addition to the Jar. I suppose the other system is Windows based and the virtual machine has access to the DLL while your other machine isn't Windows based and/or has no access to the DLL. The DLL must fit with the Jar, so maybe you had multiple JDBC-driver in your classpath and the wrong one won.

Comment: Both machines are windows based, and I made certain to point the PATH towards just one driver, sqljdbc41.  Also, the code on the home system is meant to replicate the error in the original program - I haven't reached that point in the coding yet.  I've edited the question to remove that reference, as it is not relevant.  I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: The PATH is relevant for the loading of the shared library but the operating system is preferring registered DLLs or DLLs residing in the working directory if I remember correctly. I learned that the hard way with SAP JCo 2 where the DLL was named `librfc32.dll` that also exists as completely different DLL in Windows itself. The PATH is irrelevant for the Jar, so if your classpath contains multiple JDBC-jars of different versions, the wrong DLL might be loaded. When you removed the dependencies this particular, colliding jar might have been removed from the classpath.